# Load JS on iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, load

Is it possible to load external JS on iframe? I am trying to load url to iframe and then inject some JS to do some stuff with the content. Every time i try to load the JS, it gets loaded on the main page but not on the iframe.

So far i have tried to innerHTML and then inject the JS but no success. Please any directions would be more than welcome!

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show some code.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're looking for is:

```
var tframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var script = tframe.contentWindow.document.createElement('script');
script.src = "example.js";
var tbody = tframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
tbody.appendChild( script );
```

1- Get your frame;

2- Create the script element and add the 'src';

3- Find the body (or head) and append the script there.

You also can optimize it.

Comment: Thank you for replay but this wont work because the content of the iframe is loaded within a different domain(mydomain.com is the main page and google.com is loaded in the iframe)

Comment: @sean, this is the answer, not replay, if you need from different domain, sorry, this isn't possible. And you should added this in your question.